# Any way to reconnect adb connection without unplug usb line

Tags: android, adb

Is there any way to make a phone whose status is offline to online without replug the usb line?

Comment: Just try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` commands on terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable and enable again USB debugging on the phone. Works most of the time. You can also try restarting the adb server on the desktop machine.

Comment: And also potentially restarting the USB stack of the host operating system, with or without restarting the entire host OS

Answer (score 4):

Just copy an paste in notepad with a .bat extension.

Before that make sure your `adb.exe` is included in system path or alternatively replace the 'adb' with path to adb.exe, For example:
`C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb kill-server`

```
@echo off
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
cls
echo "Android Debug Bridge Restated!!!"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an 'adb reconnect' subcommand I hadn't noticed before today: it might only be in the newer versions of adb.

There's also a device-side version, but I don't quite see how the local machine can tell the device to do that without already being connected, so perhaps that's something you can execute in a device-side shell.